# Import CSV into a Google Cloud SQL instance for MS SQL Server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Is there a way to import CSV from Google Storage into a Google Cloud SQL instance for Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Cloud SQL doesn't support importing CSV for Microsoft SQL Server.

It has to be a full backup with a single backup set (BAK file) - [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/import-export/importing#console_1).